# Customize view in fullscreen mode with custom keyboard

Tags: android, layout, view, custom-keyboard

I want to provide a modified view for a custom Android keyboard in fullscreen mode.

I found this question:[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026631/android-inputmethodservice-how-to-set-a-view-with-setextractviewview-view)

But I do not understand how to apply it.
What exactly should I write in setExtractView(View view) that I could use my own layout?

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide a modified view for a custom Android keyboard in full-screen mode you must override **onCreateExtractTextView** method in your customkeyboard class (that extends **InputMethodService**):

```
@Override
public View onCreateExtractTextView() {
// edit standard layout for full-sreen mode 
// androidsdk/platforms/android-26/data/res/layout/input_method_extract_view.xml

View inflater = super.onCreateExtractTextView(); // returns standard com.android.internal.R.layout.input_method_extract_view

// extract IDs from input_method_extract_view.xml
Resources res = Resources.getSystem(); // system resources
int id_inputExtractEditText = res.getIdentifier("inputExtractEditText", "id", "android"); // ExtractEditText
int id_inputExtractAccessories = res.getIdentifier("inputExtractAccessories", "id", "android"); // FrameLayout
int id_inputExtractAction = res.getIdentifier("inputExtractAction", "id", "android"); // ExtractButton

ExtractEditText inputExtractEditText = inflater.findViewById(id_inputExtractEditText);
FrameLayout inputExtractAccessories = inflater.findViewById(id_inputExtractAccessories);
Button inputExtractAction = inflater.findViewById(id_inputExtractAction);

// do anything with extracted views:
inputExtractEditText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.keyboard_backgound1));
inputExtractAccessories.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.keyboard_backgound2));
inputExtractAction.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.key_GradientGreen));

return inflater;
}
```